# User roles and workflow status xpages and managed bean

Tags: xpages, javabeans, status

To not have to keep repeating some validations, for example, who can see a button in a certain status of a document in the worlflow, I'm using session, scope, and session variables to store the user roles and application variable to store the Status related to each area. 
I was evaluating whether it would be better from a performance and build point of view to implement a managed bean, to return the user roles and the possible statuses of each participating workflow area. Would it be the best structure in fact? What do you think? I do not have much experience in java. How could I construct the structure in java, several methods, one for roles and the other for set of status associated with the area that would name the related method? You could return the results of this method in arrays, or there is a better return structure.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is to adopt the pageController Methodology.  Then it's more like true MVC.  This has been talked about on NotesIn9 screencast many times but basically you have a java object that's bound to your XPage. In effect it's a viewScoped bean that holds all your page logic.  Then you can have methods like isGroupMember(), hasRole() etc and calculate that on the pageInit.  There's little need to hold onto that in sessionScope in my opinion.  So for example I have this in my pageController :

```
public boolean isGroupMember(String groupName) {

        return JSFUtil.getXSPContext().getUser().getGroups().contains(groupName);

    }
```

So that's available to each page.  BUT I don't need to copy that snippet onto every page controller. In Java you can have your page controllers extend a more generic class.  so I have a "base.pageController" class.  All the specific page controllers extend that.  So this isGroupMember() code goes into the base and then it's available to be used on every XPage.  Doing it this way gives you the ability to have generic functions like this and then hold more specific function that are only for the individual page.

You can also have a hasRole() function etc...

Recommend you check out this video : http://www.notesin9.com/2016/08/25/notesin9-196-no-dependency-page-controllers/

Also  for a question like this, I recommend you just use the xpages tag.  Adding others like javabeans can bring people in who know nothing about XPages and XPages is unique enough of a beast that outsiders can cause some confusion on occasion.